# Deserializing a model with an additional field

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-orm, django-serializer

I'll be as straightforward as possible:

I have a `Challenge` model, which holds information about a certain challenge and the amount of scores it gives. Any `User` can have multiple `Submissions` for a given challenge.
When querying for a specific `Challenge`, I want to return JSON with the Challenge's information along with the maximum score that the current `request.user` has scored. Is there a way to somehow ducktype (attach) the value to the model instance and serialize it with a given Serializer class?

What I've found is that `ModelSerializer` requires the model to have that field itself, where in my case I add it dynamically.

What's a good approach to this problem and has anybody had any similar problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be done by accessing the request.user in the serializer from extra context.

In generic views the model serializer is provided with extra context. This context has the request object.

you can define a method field on your Challenge serializer

```py
class ChallengeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_max_score = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Challenge
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_user_max_score(self, obj):
        user_max_score = 0
        request = self.context.get('request', None)
        if request:
            user = request.user
            # get the user's max score
            ...
        return user_max_score
```

You can provide extra context too if you are not using generic views. Read more here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context